# jQuery window.resize() when snapped or maximized

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a function that resizes an image to match the dimensions of the window using code similar to

```
$(window).resize( function() {
     //resize image
});
```

However, this event does not fire if the window is maximized, either by using the maximize button, or by snapping the window to the top of the screen (Windows 7/8).

How can I detect when either the button or the event is used so I can properly size my image?

Comment: post a jsfiddle displaying the issue you are having.  http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Hmm, it should be triggered, that's weird...

Comment: it is because maximizing takes a bit of time. put setTimeout inside the resize function.

Comment: something like this http://jsfiddle.net/f4r9woqg/

Comment: I'm on Chrome 38, IE11 on windows 8.1 with jQuery 1.10.2 and the event is triggered properly, can you show us more of your code?

Comment: It's working now for some reason. Not sure why it wasn't working earlier, but it definitely is now. If it happens again I'll try the setTimeout solution.